# Change ordering of values in 'y' axis for dotchart

Tags: r

The following code :

```
avector <- as.vector(top.links.added.overall$Amount)
x <- as.vector(top.links.added.overall[order(avector),])
row.names(x) <- c("Yahoo" ,"Cnn", "Google")
x$color[x$Amount == 100] <- "red"
x$color[x$Amount == 500] <- "blue"
x$color[x$Amount == 1000] <- "darkgreen"
dotchart(x$Amount,
         labels = row.names(x),
         cex=.7,
         groups = x$Amount,
         gcolor = "black",
         color = x$color,
         pch=19,
         main = "Gas Mileage for Car Models\ngrouped by cylinder",
         xlab = "Miles Per Gallon")
```

Generates this graph :

[image]

Here is the format of the dataset top.links.added.overall$Amount :

[image]

here is the file dataset :

```
Amount,Name
1000,Google
500,Cnn
100,Yahoo
```

When I remove the code :

row.names(x) <- c("Yahoo" ,"Cnn", "Google")

I get row names of 1,2,3

I don't need I should need to set the names of the 'y' axis ? How can the code of the graph be amended so that the company with lowest numerical value(in this case yahoo) start at beginning of 'y' axis instead of top, which is currently what is occuring ?

Comment: In your actual data, are there only three points, or is there more than one point per group?

Comment: @David Robinson there are only three points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I can test it with the offered R data objects but perhaps something along these lines:

```
x <- as.vector(top.links.added.overall[order(-avector),])
row.names(x) <- rev( c("Yahoo" ,"Cnn", "Google") )
```

Using mathematical negation to the order argument and the `rev` (reverse) function.

Edit: I now understand your frustration,  but after looking at the code I decided to try this which seems to do it:

```
dotchart(x$Amount,
     labels = row.names(x),
     cex=.7,
     groups = -x$Amount,    # the code sorts by `as.numeric(groups)`
     gcolor = "black",
     color = x$color,
     pch=19,
     main = "Gas Mileage for Car Models\ngrouped by cylinder",
     xlab = "Miles Per Gallon")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, ive tried your code, but same result. I've attached the dataset so perhaps you can re-create ?

Comment: the comment 'the code sorts by `as.numeric(groups)`' can you elaborate on this, do you mean the sorting is already implied on 'groups' ?

Comment: That is what I inferred after being unable to deduce the correct behavior from the help page and needing to look at the source code.